# setting up rhel 5.x RPM build server for mortal users

Tags: redhat, rhel5, rpm, user-permissions

My task is to setup a RHEL 5.x build host, that can build RPMs for mortal users.

On RHEL 6.x with rpm version 4.8, I have in `/usr/lib/macros`:

```
#       Path to top of build area.
%_topdir                %{getenv:HOME}/rpmbuild
```

On RHEL 5.x with rpm version 4.4, the %{getevn:HOME} is not available.

I know that I can use `/home/someuser/.rpmmacros`:

```
%_topdir                /home/someuser/rpmbuild
```

and this will work for that user, however I don't want to do this for every user separately. Moreover, since `.rpmmacro` will not expand `${HOME}` or `~` I suspect it is unsafe to use those. This in turn make `/etc/skel` unstable for this task (or so I suspect).

So in short, my question is: **How to setup RHEL 5.x host that allow all users to build RPM packages in their home directory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `.rpmmacros` on RHEL5 I use

```
%_topdir        %(echo ${HOME}/rpm)
```

If you don't want to set up mock (but I too recommend doing that) this might help.

Comment: This solves my problem with minimal additional noise to the system.

Answer (score 5):

If at all possible, make your build server EL6. This will save you a lot of hassle later...

For a simple build box where only the occasional RPM package will be built, have your users use `mock`. You'll find it in the EPEL repository.

Using `mock` to build an RPM ensures that all of the correct build dependencies have been specified by building it in a chroot environment.

Add users who should be able to access `mock` to the `mock` group.

Then these users can build an RPM with a command like:

```
mock -r epel-5-x86_64 file.src.rpm
```

If you need to build a *lot* of RPMs, or you're creating a repository, you may want to set up an automated build server with something like [koji](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji).